# How to zip and pass-through files to browser on-the-fly?

Tags: php, stream, zip

I would like to implement feature like GMail's "get all attachments as zipped file".

Is there a way to select multiple files on server, zip them and on-the-fly pass-through to browser? (something similar to PHP's function `readfile` used for attachments streaming)

**[EDIT]**

It seems you misunderstood my intentions, all given examples require to create **and close** archive **before** its being sent, I want to stream while archive is created.

Something like unix command (from zip manual):
`zip -r - . | dd of=/dev/nrst0 obs=16k`

**[EDIT2]**

I have tons of ~2MB files (> 100) to serve, waiting for creation of tmp zip file forces to implement queuing mechanisms and takes storage space... If it can be done through stream/pipe directly to browser, why I should write tmp zip in filesyetm?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php

Comment: I've read this examples... And there is no solution.

Comment: Oh, you mean a complete, coded solution, down to the last character, as in "give me teh codez"?

Comment: @Piskvor no I can handle coding this, but I have to have some hints, not link to page that I've read carefully and its contents seems to be useless in my case.

Comment: Wait, so you're *not* trying to zip up the files into a single file? Serving that single file to the browser through `readfile` seems like a rather trivial last step.

Comment: because I have tons (>100) ~2MB files to serve... Waiting for zip file creation is involving introducing of queuing mechanisms and so on, why if it can be streamed on-the-fly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [ZipStream-PHP](http://pablotron.org/software/zipstream-php/) library - it claims to do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP host could happen to have the [zip extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php) installed.
If so, you should use it. (performance reasons)

Otherwise, for zip archiving, a good library with no dependencies is [PclZip](http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip).

There obviously was a [PEAR library](http://pear.php.net/package/Archive_Zip/redirected) for it, but is now deprecated and focus has been moved over to the PECL (binary) extension I already mentioned. (the whole PEAR ecosystem is gradually rotting down, anyway)